# Is it possible to remove the ddots when using umlcreatecall in the tikz-uml package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-uml

I am using the [TikZ-UML](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en&id=doc) package to make a [UML Sequence Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) and want to remove the ":" character (separating class and instance name) when using `\begin{umlcreatecall}[]{A}{B}`. This is possible with the `no ddots` option when using `\umlobject[no ddots, x=4]{A}` to define the lifeline initially rather than dynamically (e.g. "create" with constructor during part of the sequence)

**Example 1: "no ddots" set on umlobject**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{umlseqdiag}
        \umlobject[no ddots, x=4]{A}
        \umlobject[no ddots, x=8]{B}

        \begin{umlcall}[op=create]{A}{B}
        \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Using umlobject to create instance]

**Example 2: Need to find something similar to "no ddots" that works with umlcreatecall**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{umlseqdiag}
        \umlobject[no ddots, x=4]{A}

        \begin{umlcreatecall}[x=8]{A}{B}
        \end{umlcreatecall}
    \end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Using umlcreatecall to create instance]

**Update:** Here is an example showing why one would use `\begin{}` and `\end{}` in tikz-uml; specifically, because it is semantically how you nest function calls (need to tell the macro / tikz-uml how far down the "activation box" should extend and how the arrows are positioned).

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{umlseqdiag}
            \umlobject[no ddots, x=0]{A}
            \umlobject[no ddots, x=6]{B}
            \umlobject[no ddots, x=12]{C}

            \begin{umlcall}[op=doComplexTask(), type=synchron, with return]{A}{B}
                \begin{umlcall}[op=doSomethingWithC(), type=synchron, with return]{B}{C}
                \end{umlcall}
                % Calling these without the \begin and \end does not work
                %\umlcall[op=doMoreStuff(), type=synchron]{B}{B}
                %\umlcall[op=doStuffWithA(), type=synchron, with return]{B}{A}
            \end{umlcall}
        \end{umlseqdiag}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Example of nested call (works with umlcall or umlcreatecall)]

Comment: It would also be nice if there were a way to make the umlcreatecall force an activation box representing the constructor running in the newly created object, but I guess that would be a question for later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tikz-uml` is not very flexible and programmed like TikZ (every setting is defaulted before it is used). This means that the macro that contains `:` is defined in `\umlobject` before the options are applied. The `\umlobject` that is used by `\umlcreatecall` has no distinctive option (neither `every umlobject` or `every created umlobject`)  that can be used.

The following works but overwrites every possible `:` for `\umlobject`s *and* survives `\umlcreatecall` which is the reason the second example has `{ }` to keep the change to the `every node` style local.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{umlseqdiag}
        \umlobject[no ddots, x=2]{A}
        \umlcreatecall[x=4,/tikz/nodes={/tikzuml/obj/no ddots}]{A}{B}
        \umlobject[x=6]{C}
    \end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{umlseqdiag}
        \umlobject[no ddots, x=2]{A}
        {\umlcreatecall[x=4,/tikz/nodes={/tikzuml/obj/no ddots}]{A}{B}}
        \umlobject[x=6]{C}
    \end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it still possible to nest more (e.g. \begin{umlcall}[]{B}{C}...) inside of the umlcreatecall then? When I try adding the braces around a \begin{umlcreatecall} it only works if the corresponding \end{umlcreatecall} is also inside the braces, but in that case all of the nested content is also affected by the override. 

Also, do you know of a more flexible UML diagramming package for TeX that has similar capabilities to tikz-uml?

Comment: @iX3 Can you make an example (you can [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/116710/edit) your question) about what you mean? I literally have never used `tikz-uml`. Please not that `umlcreatecall` is not an environment but a command/macro. The bracing solution cannot work with an environment as you wish. It works as an environment because of how `\begin` and `\end` work but `\umlcreatecall` is not intended as an environment. If needed it is possible to define a command or a key that re-sets the `:` again.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example of why it might be desirable to nest calls (UML term, sorry for not knowing more TeX nomenclature). I used umlcall in the example but one could also use umlcreatecall in that same way (though there is a minor bug in how tikz-uml draws it in some cases -- I've already contacted the author regarding that).

Comment: @iX3 `umlcall` is an environment but not `\umlcreatecall`.

Comment: Oh, I see; it is different in the documentation. Is there a way to make \umlcreatecall an environment? (Sorry, I am not very familiar with TeX yet.) How then can I make nested calls (e.g. illustrating the constructor) if I can't use umlcreatecall as an environment?

Answer (score 0):

Although `\umlcreatecall` calls `\umlobject` the "no ddots" option was not defined. This was a miss. And the fix will be in the next release of tikz-uml, available soon.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! I've long since finished with the task I was working on when I posted this, but hopefully this improvement will be helpful to others and to myself if I encounter this again. Thanks for your work.